# How to remove a black frame in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer

I'd like to remove the black frame which appears at the top of each page, as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

I'm wondering if there was not an error in my preamble. How could I fix that? This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.74, 0.83, 0.9}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%paragraphes justifiés%%%%%
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%footline%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\vspace{2ex}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}Title
  \hfill\insertshortsubtitle\hfill\strut\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%NUMÉROTATION TOC%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace*{1em}\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace*{2em}\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsection\par}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\useinnertheme{circles}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PLAN%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Plan}
\tableofcontents[
  currentsection,
  sectionstyle=show/show,
  subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide
]
\end{frame}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[]{Title}
\subtitle[]{Subtitle}
\author[]{Author}
\institute[]{}
\date[] {}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{Plan}
\tableofcontents    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get any black frame using your MWE

Comment: @EladDen Even if you export the file to pdf?

Comment: No frame whatsoever ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @EladDen I added a picture to my request.

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem using the code (and I've tried on 2 platforms). So the problem is not in the code. What version of TexLive are you using? What machine? What are the commands you are using to generate the pdf? What viewer are you using? Does this line appear in other viewers?

Comment: @EladDen: same problem again, same black frame, even with TexLive 2020, installed on a Mac, using Texpad.