# Black frame appears in Beamer block?

Tags: beamer

Since yesterday, anormal *empty and black frames* appear in Beamer `begin{block}` or  `begin{alertblock}`! I have never seen this before ...

[A previously closed-post already spoke about it (from tex's user 'domi')](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561095/how-to-remove-a-black-frame-in-a-beamer-presentation) without solution ...  I reopen this "non-solved problem".

More info:

1. In log file : `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=latex 2021.2.1)  2 FEB 2021 00:04`
2. In apt-get : `texlive-base Version : 2020.20210113-1`
3. MWE to try :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\listfiles

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{ESSAI}
        \begin{block}{Définition Définition Définition Définition }
            Blabla \\
            Blabla
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

4. Here is a picture to show you what it looks like :
   [image: Slide with the black frame]

Comment: looks okay for me. Show your log file.

Comment: How can I do this ? My log file is too long to post

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    (preloaded format=latex 2021.2.1)
> ```

You seem to typeset with `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf`.

Make sure you have a recent Ghostscript installed (v. 9.52 or newer) and that `ps2pdf` is invoked with option `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY`.

Comment: I still today have that same problem. The example looks exactly like above. I am using pdflatex+dvips+ps2pdf and this gs version

GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0 (2021-03-30)

and I used the option -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY.

Comment: In your pdf viewer, please open the document properties dialogue and look for "Producer" (to verify the actual GS version used).

Comment: Acrobat tells me "PDF erstellt mit: dvips + MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25".

Comment: Now you know that the GS Version actually used is way too old.

Comment: But MiKTeX and cygwin are both up-to-date... as far as they tell.

Comment: But MiKTeX is bundled with an ancient GS. Don''t know why its maintainer doesn't update it (or removes it altogether). If you have Cygwin, open a terminal and run ps2pdf there.

Comment: Looks like the problem comes from MiKTeX which still uses the 2018 version 9.25 of gs. I posted that in their github <github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1070> now, maybe it'll change...

Comment: See github [Isse 275](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/275), that seems to a more appropriate place for continuing this discussion.