# Black frame in Beamer block

Tags: beamer

I have the same problem as in this post [Black frame appears in Beamer block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581523/black-frame-appears-in-beamer-block)

I installed a recent Ghostscript  (v. 9.54 ). Can please someone give me more details about   that ps2pdf is invoked with option -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY. What does that mean or how can I do that? I'm using TexMaker.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For Texmaker :

- You just need to change (in the file "texmaker.ini" that you can find in /home/$USER/.config/xm1/texmaker.ini) the line Tools\Ps2pdf=ps2pdf %.ps by this one :
- Tools\Ps2pdf=ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY %.ps
- save the file and exit
- go back to Texmaker and you will (normally !) see this parameter in the options config menu !
- it works for me (at least !!!) after 2 months of foggy mind

Comment: Thank you for your help and clarification. I did all that ( I checked in config menu - it is there), but no, it does not work on this computer.

Comment: No more solution yet !